# switch maptype in react-native-map

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I have the react-native map running with google for both IOS and Android.
Is there a way to have the `mapType` layer switcher like that of google maps app enabled in react-native expo app? So that user can switch mapTypes (standard, satellite, ....)

**a simplified version of the code**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    mapRegion: null,
    markers: [],
    mapType: null
  };
}

switchMapType() {
  console.log('Changing');
  this.state.mapType = 'satellite'
}

render() {
  return (
    <MapView
      provider="google"
      mapType={this.state.mapType}
    >
      <Icon
        onPress={this.switchMapType} 
      />
    </MapView>
  );
}
```

I get an undefined error when inside ***state*** `switchMapType()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it can be as simple as passing the correct style to the `mapType` prop

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

The map type to be displayed.

- standard: standard road map (default)
- none: no map
- satellite: satellite view
- hybrid: satellite view with roads and points of interest overlayed
- terrain: (Android only) topographic view
- mutedStandard: more subtle, makes markers/lines pop more (iOS 11.0+ only)

#### Binding you function

You are getting that error because probably need to bind your function so that it knows that value of `this` to use. You can do it in your constructor by putting the following in your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.switchMapType = this.switchMapType.bind(this);    
  ...
}
```

or you could convert `switchMapType` to an arrow function by changing its declaration to

```
switchMapType = () => {
  ...
}
```

or you could bind the function when you call it

```
<Icon
  onPress={this.switchMapType.bind(this} 
/>
```

You can see this article for more details https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

I prefer to use arrow functions myself.

#### Setting State

I also notice that there is an error in your function `switchMapType` with how you are setting state. You are calling `this.state.mapType = 'satellite'` You should **not** manipulate state like this. Changing state like this will not force a re-render (which is what you want) and it can lead to unexpected consequences. See this article for more on setting state https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b

If you want to change the state you should use `this.setState({ key1: value1, key2, value2 });`

So if you update your `switchMapType` function to be the following it should work

```
switchMapType = () => {
  console.log('changing');
  this.setState({ mapType: 'satellite' });
}
```

If you want to be able to toggle between the `satellite` and `standard` versions you could do something like this. This uses a ternary statement to handle the `if/else` https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-conditional-ternary-operator-explained-cac7218beeff

```
switchMapType = () => {
  console.log('changing');
  this.setState({ mapType: this.state.mapType === 'satellite' ? 'standard' : 'satellite' });
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with some code and the error I get. This is what I thought but seems like not working. Maybe a global state is needed?

Comment: Perfect I was using 'this' in the wrong context. I did figure the 'setSate'.

Comment: I am glad that it is now sorted for you :)